# jQuery animate() controlling opacity on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is what I want. I want when you click the button to go from 0 opacity to 1 opacity in 300 ms. The thing is, when I click on the button, it doesn't animate! It's so frustrating. Here is the code:

```
$(".ps").css("opacity", "0");
var showStuff = function() {
  $("#div").click(function() {
    $("#phi").animate({
      opacity: "1"
    }, 300, function() {
      $("#pname").animate({
        opacity: "1"
      }, 300);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Where you call the function showStuff?

Comment: **Here is the codepen code:**_http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyrQNj_

Comment: @N.Spagnolo Did you see my completed answer?

Comment: **Oh my god, I'm so sorry. I'm such a noob. I didn't use the onclick attribute... facepalm so hard**

Comment: @N.Spagnolo You **don't** need to use the `onclick` attribute. **Stop bolding your text, please**.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I see that you are good in HTML, CSS, JS. Do you have any tips for a 13 year old want-to-be web designer? Sorry about the bolding.

Comment: Well, learn by doing things, **but the right way**. Coz there are loads of places, you get low quality wrong information about HTML and CSS.

Comment: I'd recommend treehouse, if you are good with Video Tutorials.

Comment: @N.Spagnolo Still, Google is your friend. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ok, thanks. I'll look into it. Practice, practice, practice.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `0` and `1` are numbers and not strings. And you **aren't** calling `showStuff()` by executing the statement. If you are going to do that, you need to bind it to the event by calling the `showStuff();` inside `$(function () {});`.

```
$(".ps").css("opacity", 0);
var showStuff = function() {
  $("#div").click(function() {
    $("#phi").animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 300, function() {
      $("#pname").animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 300);
    });
  });
}
```

And you need to call `showStuff();`:

```
showStuff();
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(".ps").css("opacity", 0);
var showStuff = function() {
  $("#div").click(function() {
    $("#phi").animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 300, function() {
      $("#pname").animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 300);
    });
  });
}
showStuff();
```

```css
#div {cursor: pointer;}
#phi {background: #99f; padding: 15px;}
#pname {background: #9f9; padding: 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">#DIV - Click Here</div>
<div class="ps" id="phi">#PHI.ps</div>
<div class="ps" id="pname">#PName.ps</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery why not use fadeIn() and delay()?

Here's a fiddle – https://jsfiddle.net/xge2wnw7/

```
$("#div").click(function() {//dumbest id name for a div ever
    $("#phi").fadeIn(500);
    $("#pname").delay(1500).fadeIn(500);//wait a 1.5s and fade in the next element
});
```

Comment: One reason is that fadeIn starts you off as display none, which isn't always ideal.

Comment: Because it doesn't take up any space? Sorry for the question but I'm pretty new to javascript/jQuery and development in general. I'm very curious about best practice and such.

Comment: If you have content that is important to functionality - or SEO or screen readers or assistive technology etc - then you don't necessarily want that content to be 'Hidden' in the `display: hidden;` way. You could do height 0 overflow hidden.. or something else and avoid this. That being said - there is still a place for it. Also, jQuery animate is what is behind fadeIn() etc - and can be less smooth than desired. Velocity.js is helpful for this. http://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content for some info https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting out, you may want to think about how helpful it can be to keep things modular and the content, style, and functionality seperate. In this case, I wouldn't put an onClick in the HTML.

### HTML

```
  <div class='message-block [ js-do-something ]'>
    <p class='greeting'>Hi!</p>
    <p class='message'>I'm Noah</p>
  </div>
```

### JavaScript

You have the right idea storing this function in a variable. What if you had a few places where you want this functionality? You can just make up some parameter and pass it into the function, and then you can tailor each function call to different elements. Also - in your codepen - you don't need the `<body> / <head>` etc in the html. It is already included. Your ID's are unnecessarily overly specific - and in most cases your going to be better off with classes. Also - if you want to visually separate classes that are specifically for functionality - you can prefix the class with js- or even put them in brackets to be really sure. Anyways - those are my thoughts on the subject.

```
var showStuff = function(input) {
    var $input = $(input);
    var fadeTime = 300;
    $input.on('click', function() {
        $input.find('.greeting').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: fadeTime,
            complete: function() {
                $input.find('.message').animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, fadeTime);
            }
        });
    });
};

showStuff('.js-do-something');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/azdr40e7/)

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I will use these tips whenever I write code. It really means a lot to hear from someone with experience.

Comment: Make sure to up-vote all the answers that are helpful throughout your travels on SO. For code review, there is also a specific site for that http://codereview.stackexchange.com  too

Comment: Can't upvote. I don't have 15 reputation. Made my profile like 3 days ago. I will when I'm able to.